# Counting amount of times element appears in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, count, scripting

I am new to post on Stackoverflow but I am having lots of trouble figuring something out. I am new to the ruby language.

I would like to count the amount of times an element in the array is greater than a specific constant. The array length is between 10 and 25, this is chosen by the user. I then have the array sorted from largest to smallest. I would like to count the amount of times a value in the array is larger or equal to 35. This will be defined as the constant "Quota"

```
 puts "Enter a number between 10 and 25 to represent the number of users: "
num = gets.to_i
if num > 25 or num < 10
  puts "I said between 10 and 25. Try again"
    num = gets.to_i
end
homeDir = Array.new(num) { rand(20..50)}
homeDir.sort!{|x,y| y<=>x}
puts  homeDir
quota = 35
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use method `count`

```
homeDir.count{|el| el >= 35 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up writing this which solved my problem.

quota = 35
homeDir.each |x| puts x}
homeDir.each do |y|
    if y > quota
       counter = counter + 1
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

Since `homeDir` is sorted largest to smallest, it would generally be more efficient to use [Array#take_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-take_while) (and then `Array#size`) than [Array#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-count), as `count` must traverse the entire array.

```
def count_biggest(arr, num)
  arr.take_while { |n| n >= num }.size
end

arr = [5,4,3,2,1]

count_biggest(arr, 3) #=> 3
count_biggest(arr, 6) #=> 0
count_biggest(arr, 0) #=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my question solved.

```
print  "Enter a number between 10 and 25 to represent the number of users: "
num = gets.chomp.to_i 
while num > 25 or num < 10
  print "I said between 10 and 25. Try again: " 
    num = gets.to_i 
end
homeDir = Array.new(num) { rand(20..50)} 
homeDir.sort!{|x,y| y<=>x} 

quota = 35
counter = 0
puts"\n"
puts "Directory Sizes (in MB)"
puts "======================"

homeDir.each{|x| puts x} 
homeDir.each do |y| 
  if y > quota
    counter = counter + 1
  end
end
puts "\n"
puts "There are #{counter} users whos directories are over 35MB"
```

Comment: 1. Line 2 needs a left brace (`{`) after `each`. 2. You need to initialize `counter` to zero. 3. `if` must be paired with an `end` (or write `counter = counter + 1 if y > quota`. 4. It is inefficient because it does not make use of the fact that `homeDir` is sorted. Always test your code before posting. This is not Ruby-like code, but instead reflects a procedural approach.

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first semester taking ruby. When I answered my own question I was unable to copy and paste the code from my VM so I typed it out. Thanks for catching it, i will edit the post above.